# How to echo the variable's value containing percent signs?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, environment-variables, string

I want to echo a variable with the %'s.

Ex:

```
set var=Hello
echo %var%
```

That would obviously result in echoing "Hello", but how can I get it to just echo `%var%`?

Comment: [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551829/995714), [Ignore percent sign in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907057/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Escape <s>special characters</s> the effect by surrounding the value by **caret**s

```
echo ^%var^%
```

[image]

Comment: When I use this it just echos "Hello". I want it to echo %var% without going to the variable.

Comment: Look at the picture I am about to add inside the post.

Comment: I'm trying to use this in a batch file, and I'm using this and it won't work how it does in the prompt.

Comment: :test
set var=Hello
echo ^%var^%
goto test

Comment: Use **double** percent signs `%%var%%` inside files

Comment: @Chinggis6 - ... unless `var` is the loop variable in a `for` statement! I have no idea how may `%` signs would be needed then.

Answer (score 2):

You should double percent signs `%%var%%`

```
@echo off
set "var=Hello"
echo in my variable %%var%% ===^> %var%
pause
```